# JSON formatting to a list in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In python I get "n" number of json objects on request to an api. I need to convert this to a list and display it in django. What is the easiest way to do it.

I did use json.dumps(data) it just dumps the entire data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and then iterate on the result

Answer (score 0):

If you want data out of a .json file you can load it from a string using`json.loads(<string>)`. You can load from a file directly via `json.load(<filename>)`.

```
# Create a list
result = []

while True:
    r = json.loads(requests.get("yourAPI).text)
    result.append(r)
```

Now its just a matter of displaying the data to the user.